# Join two Queries so that the second query becomes a row in the results of query 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have two queries that I would  like to combine so i can make a chart out of the results.
The results have to be very specific or the chart will not display the  information properly

I am using MS SQL in Crystal Reports 11

Below is the results I am looking for.

```
         Date       Invoice Type        Amount 
         2012/08    Customer Payment      500 
         2012/08    Customer Invoice     1000
         2012/08    Moving Balance       1500
         2012/09    Customer Invoice      400
         2012/09    Moving Balance       1900
         2012/10    Interest               50
         2012/10    Moving Balance       1950
```

So the First query returns the following results

```
         Date       Invoice Type        Amount 
         2012/08    Customer Payment      500 
         2012/08    Customer Invoice     1000

         2012/09    Customer Invoice      400

         2012/10    Interest               50
```

and the second query returns

```
         Date       Invoice Type        Amount 

         2012/08    Moving Balance       1500
         2012/09    Moving Balance       1900
         2012/10    Moving Balance       1950
```

The second query is very long and complicated with a join .
What is the best way of joining these two queries
so that I have one column called invoice Type ( as the chart is based on this field)

that covers all the invoice types plus the moving balance

Comment: It sounds like you want to UNION the results of both queries together? See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx for an overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the place of the `Moving Balance` rows inside the result set is important.

You can do something like this:

```
select date, invoice_type, amount
from
(
  select date, invoice_type, amount from query1
  union all
  select date, invoice_type, amount from query2
)
order by date, case invoice_type when 'Moving Balance' then 1 else 0 end
```

This first appends the results of the second query to the results of the first query and then reorders the resulting list first by date and then by the invoice type in such a way that the row with Moving balance will come last.

---

With the actual queries you have given, it should look something like this:

```
select date, invoice_type, amount
from
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),case_createddate, 111) AS Date,
        case_invoicetype as invoice_type,
        Sum(case_totalexvat) as amount
    FROM   cases AS ca
    WHERE  case_primaryCompanyid = 2174 and
    datediff(m,case_createddate,getDate()) 

    union all

    select
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),ca.case_createddate, 111) AS Date,
        'Moving Balance' as Invoice_Type,
        sum(mb.Amount) as Amount
    from
        cases as ca
        left join (
            select
                case_primaryCompanyId as ID,
                case_createdDate,
                case_TotalExVat as Amount
            from
                cases
        ) mb
        on ca. case_primaryCompanyId = mb.ID  
        and ca.case_createdDate >= mb.case_CreatedDate
    where
        ca.case_primaryCompanyId = 2174 and
        ca.case_createdDate > DATEADD(m, -12, current_timestamp)
    group by
        case_primaryCompanyId,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),ca.case_createddate, 111)
    order by  ca.case_primaryCompanyid, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),ca.case_createddate, 111)
)
order by date, case invoice_type when 'Moving Balance' then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: I have put in the following code but it wont accept it and keeps giving me the following error "Incorrect syntax near ')'"      select * from (query 1 union all  query 2 )  see query above

Comment: Thanks Daniel, am on sleepy mode today, thats perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union and can use Order by clause

```
Select  * from (Query 1
Union
        Query 2
)  as a Order by a.Date Asc
```